# can i make a question about this? tissue popped out in place of subungal hematoma

Tags: discussion, support, moderation

see these 4 photos of my finger: https://photos.app.goo.gl/JGrpqW4X6maUGUNc6 . the nail was pressed on may 3. at may 13 seems the tissue was normal. at may 22 or may 21 something strange appeared under nail. june 12 i opened nail and see tissue popped out. also you can see there that new nail has grown and it pushes to the tumor. now, the tumor has began to dry, as you can see in the june 17 photo. so, i hope, it is going to be normal.

can i ask, what is this medical condition? how it is called/named and what are some basic info/stats/knowledge about this, possible implications/complications? as i know, there is special tissue under the nail. nail bed. so, this creates questions. can this nail just cut the tumor off by itself when it grows, and be normal? does the nail bed regenerate properly in proper place by itself?

Comment: It will be very difficult for you to frame such a question in a way that avoids it being considered personal medical advice.